# Выполнение скрипта на определенной странице

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, можно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся только на определенной странице?

Comment: да, всякими разными способами

Comment: а можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, проверять текущую страницу, используя "чистый" JS:

```
if(window.location.toString().indexOf('onepage.htm')>0)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот неплохая [статья на эту тему](https://blog.lisogorsky.ru/js-css-individual-inclusion), с примерами:

В двух словах:

1. через PHP: с помощью `preg_match()` определяем URL (либо группу URL). Если соответствует нужному - вставляем стиль или скрипт;
2. с помощью JavaScript: используем `document.location` и при совпадении нужного нам URL добавляем в `head` скрипт следующим образом:

   ```
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(dopScriptElement);
   ```